# Maintain Column Filter State using Materal React Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, javascript-objects

I am using [Material React Table](https://www.material-react-table.com/) to display the list of records. How can I maintain the filter state while initializing the component? (In case the user navigates away and comes back etc.)

In my column, I have a multi-select and text field variant filter.

```
    const columns = useMemo(
() => [
  {
    accessorKey: 'description',
    header: 'Description',
    filterVariant: 'text',
    size: 150,
  },
  {
    accessorKey: 'task_type',
    header: 'Type',
    size: 90,
    filterVariant: 'multi-select',
  }
],
[]
```

)

This is my Table.

```
<MaterialReactTable
      columns={columns}
      data={rows}
      enableStickyHeader
      enablePinning
      initialState={{ density: 'compact' }}
      enableFacetedValues
      enableFilterMatchHighlighting
      muiTablePaperProps={{
        elevation: 0,
        sx: {
          borderRadius: '0'
        }
      }}
      muiTableContainerProps={{ sx: { maxHeight: '350px' } }}
      
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my assumption is correct you need the filter to not been changed if the user select a filter and navigates to another page and reverts back to the page

you can use a custom function for this. See this documentation [Material Table Custom Filter Function](https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/column-filtering#add-custom-filter-functions)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Based on the documentation, a props (onColumnsFilterChange) and add state props to the table. It's working now. Cheers!